# Почему не показывается ответ?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

```
    <script>
    var req="http://api.vk.com/method/video.getEmbed?oid=-76325697&video_id=170120943&embed_hash=6c801fdbe6a49ce2"
$.ajax({
    url : req,
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(msg){
        console.log(msg.response[0]);
    }
});
    </script>
```

Что здесь неправильно? Или почему ответ не показывается?

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно `msg.response[0]`, потому что возвращается объект `response`, а не массив.

```
var req="http://api.vk.com/method/video.getEmbed?oid=-76325697&video_id=170120943&embed_hash=6c801fdbe6a49ce2"
$.ajax({
    url : req,
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(msg){
        console.log(msg.response); // тут
    }
});
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что ничего нет в консоли? Тогда смотрите ``msg`` или ответ сервера где-то в devtools браузера.

Comment: Сам запрос есть, но вот ответа на странице нет.
Вот ссылка: http://serial-base.ucoz.ru/test.html

Comment: 1. ``responce`` !== ``response`` :)
2. На странице ничего не появится - появится в консоли браузера.

Comment: Ну а как можно передать переменную url360 в плеер?

Comment: Это уже вопрос, достойный отдельного обсуждения.

Comment: А можно с вами связаться как то?

Comment: Нет. Я придерживаюсь мнения, что ответы/помощь могут быть бесплатными до тех пор, пока они открыты для всех.